# Regex text date

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex matcher, where by the string should start with 'Feb' , have a space, and then followed by 2 digits.

```
    String x = "Feb 04 |";

    String regex = "^Feb d{2}";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);


    Pattern pattern =   Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher =   pattern.matcher(x);
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.print("FOUND");
    }
```

`'String regex = "^Feb";'` does well to detect if it starts with Feb, but trying to detect there is a space followed by 2 digits.

Comment: but `d` will just match the letter `d` - check the documentation [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\d` is a digit (and in Java strings you need an additional \ to escape the first one: `"^Feb \\d{2}"`)

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern `^Feb\s\d{2}` matches Feb, a white space, and two digits.

[edit]

`^Feb\s\d{2}.*$` if you want to match the full string

Comment: be aware that `\s` also matches tab and other whitespace characters (`[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`)